# import bulk data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, performance, bulkinsert

So I'm trying to import some sales data into my MySQL database. The data is originally in the form of a raw CSV file, which my PHP application needs to first process, then save the processed sales data to the database.

Initially I was doing individual `INSERT` queries, which I realized was incredibly inefficient (~6000 queries taking almost **2 minutes**). I then generated a single large query and `INSERT`ed the data all at once. That gave us a 3400% increase in efficiency, and reduced the query time to just over **3 seconds**.

But as I understand it, `LOAD DATA INFILE` is supposed to be even quicker than any sort of `INSERT` query. So now I'm thinking about writing the processed data to a text file and using `LOAD DATA INFILE` to import it into the database. Is this the optimal way to insert large amounts of data to a database? Or am I going about this entirely the wrong way?

I know a few thousand rows of mostly numeric data isn't a lot in the grand scheme of things, but I'm trying to make this intranet application as quick/responsive as possible. And I also want to make sure that this process scales up in case we decide to license the program to other companies.

**UPDATE:**

So I did go ahead and test `LOAD DATA INFILE` out as suggested, thinking it might give me only marginal speed increases (since I was now writing the same data to disk twice), but I was surprised when it cut the query time from over 3300ms down to ~240ms. The page still takes about ~1500ms to execute total, but it's still noticeably better than before.

From here I guess I'll check to see if I have any superfluous indexes in the database, and, since all but two of my tables are InnoDB, I will look into optimizing the InnoDB buffer pool to optimize the overall performance.

Comment: I do know this question was posted ages ago, but i have to say that the difference between one bulk INSERT and LOAD DATA INFILE is the time saved. I went from 30 secs / more with INSERT to about 10 secs loading a ~11000 line with 30 columns CSV file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` is very fast, and is the right way to import text files into MySQL.  It is one of the recommended methods for speeding up the insertion of data -up to 20 times faster, according to this:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html

Assuming that writing the processed data back to a text file is faster than inserting it into the database, then this is a good way to go.

Answer (score 4):

LOAD DATA or multiple inserts are going to be much better than single inserts; LOAD DATA saves you a tiny little bit you probably don't care about that much.

In any case, do quite a lot but not too much in one transaction - 10,000 rows per transaction generally feels about right (NB: this is not relevant to non-transactional engines). If your transactions are too small then it will spend all its time syncing the log to disc.

Most of the time doing a big insert is going to come from building indexes, which is an expensive and memory-intensive operation.

If you need performance,

- Have as few indexes as possible
- Make sure the table and all its indexes fit in your innodb buffer pool (Assuming innodb here)
- Just add more ram until your table fits in memory, unless that becomes prohibitively expensive (64G is not too expensive nowadays)

If you must use MyISAM, there are a few dirty tricks there to make it better which I won't discuss further.

Answer (score 2):

Guys, i had the same question, my needs might have been a little more specific than general, but i have written a post about my findings here.

http://www.mediabandit.co.uk/blog/215_mysql-bulk-insert-vs-load-data

For my needs load data was fast, but the need to save to a flat file on the fly meant the average load times took longer than a bulk insert.  Moreover i wasnt required to do more than say 200 queries, where before i was doing this one at a time, i'm now bulking them up, the time savings are in the region of seconds.

Anyway, hopefully this will help you?

Comment: Interesting. This is definitely good to know for many use cases, though I'm a little confused as to how you got the 0.0013sec figure. (I'm not good with statistics.)

Comment: Lese: This is to do with standard deviation.  My understanding of standard deviation is it shows how much variance there is from the average. (Excel did the calculation for me).  My point was the standard deviation for bulk was less than that of load data.  This to me meant that BULK was most consistantly faster.  Which for me was the most important factor when deciding about this.  Mainly because this was working on a live site.

Hopefully this makes sense?  Have a look here for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with your approach.  I'm not sure how much faster LOAD DATA INFILE is compared to bulk INSERT, but I've heard the same thing, that it's supposed to be faster.

Of course, you'll want to do some benchmarks to be sure, but I'd say it's worth writing some test code.